# Unable to write a rewrite rule in .htaccess for my php website

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is v2.example.com and I am trying to write a .htaccess rule but unable.

I want this : v2.example.com/ABCDEFGH

And I want to get the value ABCDEFGH as a parameter like it is v2.example.com/index.php?id=ABCDEFGH

can anyone please help me sorting out this problem.

I tried this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

this will crash as it goes into infinite loop, as index.php is further rewritten to index.php?id=index.php and so on

## solution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)$   _index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

that is create page `_index.php`, and rewrite all pages not having `_` to this page, this way it will not go into infinite loop, you can choose `~` instead of `_` if you think you will need _ in ur parameters